# Number of ISA relationship triangles in an Entity-Relationship Diagram

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams

The following two diagrams are nearly identical. However, in one, there are two ISA triangles from the Entity "Movie" and in the other there is just one.

What is the difference in meaning?

[image: Two ISA Triangles]

[image: One ISA Triangle]

Answer (score 1):

ISA in First diagram has no point. ISA is used as "either".

Movie **CAN BE** a Cartoon **or** Natural or movie **MUST BE** a cartoon **or** Natural.

There is no point to append an ISA while there is no **either** condition